# Applying CSS property in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on 'OnClick' functionality in jQuery. When we click Div property other divs should fade out.

Please find the code below.
HTML:

```
<div>1</div>
<div class="ree">2</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div class = "bar">
     <div class="nike">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>4</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.nike').on('click',function ()
              {
$('div:not(.nike)').css('opacity','0.2')

              });
```

Here When I click on Div Class 'Nike', Except 'Nike' all Div classes should fade out. But here All Divs including Nike is fading out.

http://jsfiddle.net/6V8hr/5/

Thanks all

Comment: Because your "nike" div is contained by other DIVs? :)

Comment: so.. should i remove those parent divs?

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/6V8hr/8/

Comment: I will be needing that for future implementations.. :( is there anyway to do without removing those?

Comment: You could do it the brute force way and explicitly add the opacity of the other divs on click

Comment: @karthikr: thank you much karthi.. you are a star.!

Comment: Check this one http://jsfiddle.net/H17737/nr5bL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have nested DIVs, those parent DIVs are getting faded out, also causing your `nike` div to fade out.

While this code isn't perfect...  it works for what you need it to.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6V8hr/10/)**

```
$('.nike').on('click',function () {
   $('div').not('.foo').not('.bar').not('.nike').css('opacity','0.2')
});
```

So I'm basically listed the classes in your tree containing nike, making sure none of those are affected.

Comment: Perhaps having a class for the divs that *might* be faded (including the one you don't want to fade for this click) and then using .not() against **that** list.

Comment: That's a real lack of genericity.

Answer (score 1):

I read the HTML all 10 kinds of wrong. Below is the revised, short sweet and to the point. Add `class="hideThis"` to any divs you would want to be "hidden". If you have multiple sibling divs that you want to hide/show on click, you could give them all the `hideThis` class and replace the `$('.nike')` with `$('.hideThis')`

```
$('.nike').click(function() {
  $(this).css('opacity','1'); //in case something else got clicked & hid this
  $('.hideThis').not($(this)).css('opacity','0.2'); //hide everything else
}
```

Comment: Is this right?  `<div>1<div>` is not a parent div of `nike`.  `foo` and `bar` are parent divs...  but `foo` would be a sibling of `<div>1<div>`.

Comment: @Charlie74: thats correct.. but i tried that method in jsfiddle.. didn't work.. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.nike').on('click', function() {
    $('div:not(.nike):not(:has(.nike))').css('opacity', '0.2');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this code seems better suited

```
$('.nike').on('click', function () {
  $('div').each(function () {
    if ($('.nike').closest($(this)).length == 0) {
        $(this).css('opacity', '0.2');
    }
  })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H17737/nr5bL/

Comment: @H17737.. thank you so much.. Is there anyway to bring those numbers back to original if i click back on div class 'Nike' again?